# Gender pay gap dataset

Tags: economics

I'm looking for detailed data from which I can explore the gender pay gap, I'm not looking for any country in particular, but the more the better.

The important point for this is how detailed the data is: age, occupation, college degree, hours worked a week...
Basically, I'm giving for granted that there is a pay gap and I want to look into the reasons for this.

If there are datasets already available for this, awesome! 
If not, I'm looking for pointers to make an efficient search.

EDIT:

I was pointed to this site:

https://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/2017menu_tables.asp

Which contains quite good data, the issue here is that the format of these tables is pretty messy, the number of columns is not fixed and for some cases there is more than one field for each cell (E.G: standar error) and when converted to .CSV there are empty columns in the middle, is not imposible to work with this data but it can be very time consuming to fix all the files to start an EDA.

https://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d17/tables/dt17_502.30.asp

[image]

Comment: now.org is likely to have links to some data (or you can contact them directly for help), but it might be biased.

Answer (score 3):

I think the IPUMs data is a pretty good place to start: https://usa.ipums.org/usa/

It has individual level data for Americans that includes gender, compensation, education, family status, marital status, occupational field, and many other variables relevant to the paygap.